# Is there any benefit from completing 'belief songs'?

Tags: godus

When you have a number of abodes, you start noticing that collecting more of the belief orbs in a quick succession generates a series of tones. These tones form some well-known songs, for example Greensleeves or Drunken Sailor. The tone series restarts after a while of not picking a belief orb with a dissonant tone, but if you manage to collect enough of the orbs in one series, you will reach the end of the song and a purple note is displayed. Next time you start to collect, a different song is played.

Now, is there any other benefit to completing these songs, besides hearing the song and the purple note? For example bonus belief or such (I can't manage to discern if the bonus belief is the case because the numbers go by too fast for me to count).

Comment: i seem to reliably get "the blue danube" starting from grass lodges.  unsure if it's based on "era" or building that you started with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Godus gamepedia](http://godus.gamepedia.com/Belief#Music), you get bonus belief for completing each song:

> Every time the players select an abode with ready belief, or hovered through it while leashing, they will notice a tone playing. Thus, alternatively tapping on abodes with ready belief one by one, the player can complete the song, rewarded with extra belief.